# Yap suddenly fails to print .dvi files and .ps files

Tags: miktex2.9, dvi, yap

dvi-Files that used to print with Yap (up to March 9) don't now (from March 12 onwards),
although Yap shows them on screen, nor does "File - Print - Postscript" work. Instead error messages are displayed.
I am using MiKTeX 2.9 installed October 2020, not changed or updated since; HP LaserJet printer; Windows 10 system, automatically updated between the above dates.

Comment: well I can confirm that it doesn't work. But I haven't used yap to print or view for years, so I can't say when it started to fail. Make a bug report at the miktex github site.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice (even though the close notice mentions the option to 'ask a new question'). It is better to add details to the previous question (for example all information given by you in comments, and maybe the LaTeX code for a small example file that shows the issue), then that question will be considered for reopening - and this one deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with StackExchange. The error message from trying to "Print Postscript ..." a .dvi file reads "The MiKTeX print utility failed for some reason".

Comment: Perhaps I should add: I'm using Windows 10 Home, version 2004.

Comment: you are in the wrong place here. Notify the miktex maintainer. Btw: there is already a bug report and you could comment that you have the same problem: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/745